# Decoding Json String From Javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following json sent (POST) from my javascript to the php

```
function boardToJSON() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        "pieces" : gPieces,          // gpieces and gdestinations is an array
        "destinations" : gDestinations,
        "boardSize" : kBoardHeight        // boardSize is an integer value 9

    });
```

// Below function is called on Button Click and **url** **contains PATH to the php file.**

```
function makeMove() {
    var move;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: boardToJSON(),
        success: function(msg) {
            move = msg;     
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Unable to connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested URL of HalmaAI not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Data from HalmaAI was not JSON :( Parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }

    });
```

On the server side (in PHP) I am trying to get it like this

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
$myJson = json_decode($jsonString);

echo $myJson["boardSize"];   // also tried  $myJson.boardSize etc
```

Issue is that I am unable to decode JSON in PHP. Can someone guide me here please ? Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. You say you're posting the JSON, but the PHP you show is attempting to load the JSON from a file, not receive it from POST.

Comment: @Utkanos that is the raw post body...

Comment: How are you sending the data? What did `var_dump()` tell you you got?

Comment: Actually it is a POST method given by my teacher and he said that in this was you can retrieve the posted data from JavaScript FILE in php. I am adding more code to above . Gimme a minute

Comment: @AbraCadaver because the entire `$_POST` superglobal is not json_encoded; only a child element in that array can be.

Comment: then $myJson = json_decode($_POST['child']);

Comment: @SetSailMedia `$_POST` doesn't come into play here.  He is trying to read JSON from PHP raw input.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($jsonString)`?

Comment: @MikeBrant I was responding to AbraCadaver, not the OP

Comment: please var_dump($jsonString). I guess you are not getting the desired format from input stream. If it so you can go for $_POST

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `contentType` property on AJAX request to `application/json`.  This will set proper header on request such that server will not attempt to populate `$_POST` in favor of you working with the raw input.

```
function makeMove() {
    var move;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json"
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: boardToJSON(),
        success: function(msg) {
            move = msg;     
        }
    });
}
```

Assuming this works, you can access the `boardSize` property at:

```
$myJson->boardSize;
```

The other problem you have is that since you specify `dataType: "json"` you need to make sure you send back valid JSON, which you currently are not.

This is not valid JSON:

```
echo $myJson["boardSize"];
```

This would be (of course this is a trivial example):

```
$returnObj = new stdClass();
$returnObj->boardSize = $myJson->boardSize;
echo json_encode($returnObj);
```

Comment: Now how can I get value of boardSize on the server side ??

Comment: No it says the data returned is not Json.

Comment: On Server Side I am going this.

$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
$myJson = json_decode($jsonString);
$returnObj = new stdClass();
$returnObj->boardSize = $myJson->boardSize;
echo json_encode($returnObj);

Comment: @farhangdon And what result do you get?

Comment: Json returned in Not Valid .

Comment: @farhangdon So have you tried to debug?  Have yo done `var_dump()` of say `$jsonString`, `$myJson`, etc.?

Comment: Please see I have updated the CODE in question.
I got this error 
alert('Data from HalmaAI was not JSON :( Parse failed.');

Comment: @farhangdon OK. So somehwere along the line, you are not getting what you expect in the variables.  You need to do some debugging as I mentioned to see what the variables differ from what you expect.

Comment: When I do var_dump()  it works like and echo and it returns to the javascript and the error remains same. I dont know How can I check that what came in POST to the server :/

because request is sent from javascript and after it  php echos/var_dump  the control is returned to the javascript. So how can I debug the value in PHP ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63440/discussion-between-farhangdon-and-mike-brant).

Answer (score 0):

If you want decode json to array in PHP, you should set the 2nd argument of `json_decode` to `true`.
Example:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
$myJson = json_decode($jsonString, true);
echo $myJson["boardSize"];
```